# Android File IO: Not saving/not loading the data

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, file-io

Background:

I am using three fragments and one activity in my application. Two fragments use recyclerViews and the other uses an expandableListView.

Problem:

I am trying to properly program the onPause(), onResume(), onStop(), and onRestart() methods to save the state of my application when the home, back, or switch views buttons are pressed.

To save the state of the program and load it when it comes back I have created the save() and load() methods in my one and only activity.

```
//from the end of onCreate
    load();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mRef = new Firebase("https://sure-7856d.firebaseio.com/");
}
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    save();
}
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    save();
}
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    load();
}
@Override
protected void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    load();
}
```

In the save method I get the adapters from my 2 recyclerViews and my expandableListView`s ArrayList that keeps track of which checkboxes are checked.
After that I put them each into a temporary Arraylist then I add each of those ArrayLists to a single arraylist that will be saved to the file.

```
private void save(){

    //saved_data = new File("saved_data");


    /*try {
        if(saved_data.exists()==false){
            //saved_data.createNewFile();
            saved_data.setWritable(true);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    File myFile;
    try{
        myFile = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), "dir/save_data.bin");
        myFile.mkdirs();
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FILENAME = myFile.getName();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    OneFragment f20 = (OneFragment) frags.get(0);
    TwoFragment f21 = (TwoFragment) frags.get(1);
    ThreeFragment f22 = (ThreeFragment) frags.get(2);

    ArrayList saveTasks = f20.adapter.getList();
    ArrayList saveReqs = f21.adapter.getList();
    ArrayList saveMap = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(f22.listAdapter!=null) {
        if (f22.listAdapter.getExport() != null) {
            saveMap = f22.listAdapter.getExport();
        }
    }


    ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
    results.add(saveTasks);
    results.add(saveReqs);
    results.add(saveMap);

    ObjectOutputStream oos1 = null;
    FileOutputStream fos1 = null;

    try {
        fos1 = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos1 = new ObjectOutputStream(fos1);
        oos1.writeObject(results);
        oos1.close();
        fos1.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(oos1  != null){
            try {
                oos1.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In the load code I get the object from the file and update the adapters to their previous state.

```
private void load(){

    //saved_data = new File("saved_data");

    ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    if(FILENAME==null){
        return;
    }
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(FILENAME);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        while (true) {
            results = (ArrayList)(ois.readObject());
        }
    } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
        if (!e.eof) try {
            throw e;
        } catch (OptionalDataException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < results.size();i++){
            if(i == 0){
                frags.set(0,results.get(i));
            }
            else if(i == 1){
                frags.set(1,results.get(i));
            }
            else if(i == 2){
                frags.set(2,results.get(i));
            }
            else{

            }
    }

}
```

When I press the square button at the bottom of the emulator and go back to it one of a few things happen

It crashes saying the file could not be found

```
 W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

And this error points to the load method as the point of failure specifically

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
```

When I hit the triangle button nothing happens in logcat, everything is gone upon returning, and the app loses its functions of adding strings to lists on both recyclerViews and displaying both lists in the expandableListView.

Hitting the center circle button and going back to the app is fine nothing breaks.

Since I`m getting a file not found error I think that the file isn`t getting written

I have searched Stack for a solution and I am new to File IO and fragments, so I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Do you want the state of your app be lifetime persistent or just between app navigation?
If latter you should use `Activity onSaveInstanceState()` for saving the states and`onRestoreInstanceState()` or similar ones for restoring.

Comment: I`m looking for between app navigation. Thank you I will look into that.